# How to insert lead data in Dynamics CRM 365?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-web-api, dynamics-crm-365

I am using the Web API of Dynamics CRM. I am able to get the OAuth token but my next step is to insert the lead data in CRM.

```
/api/data/v8.2
```

Can any one help me which method I need to call to insert the lead data in CRM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you read documentation on MSDN?: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328090.aspx

Simply post a json to proper url, below you have an example:

```
POST [Organization URI]/api/data/v8.2/leads HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
OData-MaxVersion: 4.0
OData-Version: 4.0
Accept: application/json

{
    "subject": "Test lead",
    "companyname": "Contoso",
    "firstname": "John",
    "lastname": "Smith",
    "emailaddress1": "test@gmail.com",
    "telephone1": "345345345",
    "mobilephone": "345345345" 
}
```

Comment: I am able to insert data in first name , last name but not able to insert data in email ,phone no.
Can you please tell me other property so that i am able to insert the data.

Comment: I'm not sure what problem yo uhave, but I updated my answer with email and example phones. This is standard JSON, you just add attribute name and value for any other value...

Comment: where yuo find these attributes. I tried to find out specification but not able to find . can you please tell me how to insert address as well. thanks for your hep.

Comment: Go to Settings -> Customizations -> Customize the system, choose Entities ->Lead -> Fields and you will have all the fields on Lead